# does "vagrant destroy" erase apache configs?

Tags: vagrant

I'm new to vagrant, I'm using scotchbox.

I've configured a couple of vhosts in apache.

I guess the right way to do this would have been to change the provisionning of my box (as it's the aim of vaghrant right?) but i did the old school way by simpply editing my config files and so on...

Now my question is :

if i run `vagrant destroy`, do i loose all my configs?
is there any other command (vagrant halt, vagrant suspend?) that would allow me to **reboot my host machine without loosing my config**?

Comment: downvoting a question starting with "i'm a newbie on a subject" ... how clever !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vagrant destroy` will remove entire VM so any changes that were made manually will be lost. Vagrant `halt` only turns of the power so to speak so nothing is lost. If you run your machine again or reboot it all your data is save, just don't use `--provision` option that will recreate all initial configuration.

Comment: so if i get you right, i run `vagrant halt`, reboot the host, then `vagrant up` and my manual changes are still there?

Comment: yes, otherwise it would be hard to develop something that requires for example database without turning off your host machine :)